# Where is a signal coming from

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, signals

I have run a shell script on a solaris server, it's a very complex script which would call some other shell or perl scripts and the whole execution costs a long time-a few hours.

The strange thing is, it always exits abnormally. I use "truss" command to record the system call of shell process. It indicates the cause seems the arrival the signal #15  SIGTERM. But I have no idea where is the signal #15 coming from? Is there any way can detect a signal come from which process?

my server info:

```
uname -a
SunOS zsups379 5.10 Generic_144488-07 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-880
```

The slice of truss output(23528 is the main process, 25213 is the child process of 23528):

```
25213/2:        read(8, "17A6 G8A078A 58E15 P9E 5".., 8192)     = 8192

25213/1:            Received signal #15, SIGTERM, in lwp_wait() [caught]

23528:      Received signal #15, SIGTERM, in waitid() [caught]

25213/2:        write(9, " X #85 f @F5 Z88CAFB J\n".., 515)     = 515

23528:  waitid(P_ALL, 0, 0xFFBFD958, WEXITED|WTRAPPED|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED) Err#91 ERESTART

25213/1:        lwp_wait(2, 0xFFBFD39C)                         Err#91 ERESTART

25213/1:        lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0xFFBFFEFF, 0x0000FFF7) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]

23528:  lwp_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, 0x00004000, 0x00000000) = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily trace all signals sent to your process by using a dtrace script similar to that one:

```
proc:::signal-send
/ args[2] == 15 /
{
    printf("Process %d (%s) killing %d (%s)\n",
            pid, execname, args[1]->pr_pid, args[1]->pr_fname);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a new direction for me, as I have never used dtrace before.I will have a try.

Comment: In fact, on a Solaris system, you'll find `/usr/demo/dtrace/sig.d` as an example of what DTrace can do. Simply try that out.

Comment: @FrankH: the script I suggested (and now fixed) is targeting user1038919's signal and will show any SIGTERM occurring as soon as it happens. The demo one is doing aggregated statistics for all signals, which is certainly interesting but less suited to initiate the investigation.

Answer (score 2):

<s>One of the problems with signals as a method of IPC (inter-process communication) is that there is no way to find out where the signal came from.</s>  Since you presumably do not see a `kill(0, SIGTERM)` in the `truss` output, you can assume that the signal does not come from the trussed process.  Therefore, it must come from somewhere else - either (perhaps, but unlikely) the system itself, or (more likely) another process.

*My memory is failing - partly because I've never used the mechanism...*

There is in POSIX the [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) system call with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag and the `siginfo_t` structure defined in [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

> The `<signal.h>` header shall define the `siginfo_t` type as a structure, which shall include at least the following members:
>
> ```
> int           si_signo  Signal number. 
> int           si_code   Signal code. 
> int           si_errno  If non-zero, an errno value associated with 
>                         this signal, as described in <errno.h>. 
> pid_t         si_pid    Sending process ID. 
> uid_t         si_uid    Real user ID of sending process. 
> void         *si_addr   Address of faulting instruction. 
> int           si_status Exit value or signal. 
> long          si_band   Band event for SIGPOLL. 
> union sigval  si_value  Signal value.
> ```

Comment: Yes, I have also noticed the siginfo_t type. Indeed I can write a signal handler to get siginfo_t in my main process like process 23528 in my example and the signal comes from its child 25213. But if the signal is issued and transmitted layer by layer, for instance, process 25213 isn't the real signal sender, it just captures the signal generated by other process. The source code of process 25213 is unchangeable for me so that I can't add a signal handler for it. So just like that, I can't add signal handler to every layer child process. How can I get the original sender process?